# Options besides table valued parameters for passing table variable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have many stored procedures that are used for reports. All these procedures follow the following format. In essence, the SP does work, and the final result is inserted into a @table variable:

```
ALTER procedure dbo.usp_GetComplexData    
as     

declare @MyTable table                    
(                    
    Col1 varchar(20),
    Col2 varchar(20)
)

-- Here the SP is doing lots of work with lots of tables.
-- The result inserted in @MyTable

SELECT Col1, Col2 from @MyTable
```

Now I need to send via email (in html format) the results of these stored procedures.

I also have `SpCustomTable2HTML` (found [at Symantec](https://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/sql-stored-procedure-convert-sql-table-html-v10)) that converts any table into an html table. It doesn't need the table schema to do its work; it simply takes the table and returns an html table.

So here's the stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure usp_sendHtmlReportViaEmail
as
DECLARE @HTML1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
    drop TABLE #results
select top 50 * into #results From MyTable
EXEC SpCustomTable2HTML '#results', @HTML1 OUTPUT, '', ''

EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='My profile',
@recipients='test@Example.com',
@subject='Test message',
@body_format = 'HTML',
@body=@HTML1
```

I would like to somehow call `usp_sendHtmlReportViaEmail` from `usp_GetComplexData` by sending it `@MyTable` as parameter. I was reading about [table valued parameters](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/), but that requires to create a TVP for each table that I would pass. I don't want to create a specific TVP for each table that will be passed to `usp_sendHtmlReportViaEmail`.

Are there any other options?

Thanks.

Comment: In SSRS you can export report to html or mhtml(with embedded images). Consider to choose SSRS to generate reports instead of doing this work yourself

Comment: I considered it, but I thought it would be more difficult considering that it would need to be a shceduled job. These reports are sent on a schedule (ie. every hour).

Comment: In my company we often send table in way you provided in question. If you do not want to use any reporting service it's the best way

Comment: @MikhailLobanov, you're saying not to use SSRS?

Comment: No, SSRS is better for reports. One day you will want to send complex reports and some will be sent with SSRS and some - with `sp_send_dbmail` procedure. It's not good. But you are asking about sending reports without SSRS, and your query is good for this

Comment: There are schedules in SSRS (for each schedule SSRS creates job in SQL Agent)

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined to use SQL, then you should look into using a [global temporary table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_1). You have to make sure you clean up after your code executes to avoid using too many resources, but it might be a valid approach for you.

At the end of your `usp_GetComplexData` procedure, just insert the data into a `##TemporaryTable` and use that as the parameter to `usp_sendHtmlReportViaEmail`. Since I don't know what exactly you do with the table variable, I won't replace it, but you could potentially replace it with the temporary table instead.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetComplexData
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
    (/*... Columns ...*/);

    -- Do complex data stuff...

    SELECT
        *
    INTO
        ##MyTempTable
    FROM
        @MyTable;

    EXECUTE usp_sendHtmlReportViaEmail '##MyTempTable';

    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        @MyTable;

END
```